# How To Access US Trade with Filipino Passport

Tags: stocks

I would like to open a US trading account and have access to US stock exchange but I'm from the Philippines, hence I don't have SSN. Can you recommend a solution for this. I have a US bank account. Also, I tried Ameritrade, I sent my requirements via fax, which I found on their website, but I haven't heard back from them and it's been 2 weeks. Basically, I want to buy US stocks with lower fees cos If I do it from the Philippines fees are usually expensive since I have to hire a broker or go to a bank and have them do it for me.

Comment: You *might* be able to open an account with Interactive Brokers.

Answer (score 1):

for a broker comparison i would recommend brokerchooser.com under broker reviews. there you'll find a list of all the brokers available in your country.
ameritrade doesn't appear on the list. personally i use trading 212 because they have 0 commission etfs and stocks but no options. for options you can either use interactive brokers or tastyworks.

Comment: Good source for finding a broker.